# How to add a function to the button generated by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I have a table in HTML that shows data about products. Well, in this table I want to add a button that allows the user to delete that product if he wishes, that button will be automatically generated together with the information in the table through JavaScript.

```
<!-- This is my table in HTML -->
<table id="tableVolume" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>  Volume  </th>
            <th>  Serial Number  </th>
            <th>  Situation  </th>
            <th>  Delete  </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The table without information should look like this:

[image]

In JavaScript I have a function that will work with this table, one to add blank lines and another to add information, including the delete button.

```
// Function to add lines to a table
$scope.insertLines = function () {
    
    var tableS = document.getElementById("tableVolume");
    var numOfRowsS = tableS.rows.length;
    var numOfColsS = tableS.rows[numOfRowsS-1].cells.length;
    var newRowS = tableS.insertRow(numOfRowsS);

    for (var k = 0; k < numOfColsS; k++)
    {
        newCell = newRowS.insertCell(k);
        newCell.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    }
};

//Function to add informations to a table
$scope.infosnaTabelaSecun = function(number) {
    if (FindCodigo != null && matchTraco == null) {
        for (var k = 0; k < $scope.FindSerialNumber.length; k++) {
            tableVolume.rows[number+k+1].cells[0].innerHTML = volTotal;
            tableVolume.rows[number+k+1].cells[1].innerHTML = lines[(5+k)].substring(4); 
            tableVolume.rows[number+k+1].cells[2].innerHTML = "";
            tableVolume.rows[number+k+1].cells[3].innerHTML = "<button class='button-one' onclick='DeleteSrlNumber()'> <i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button>";
        }
    }
    else if (matchTraco != null) {
        for (var k = 0; k < (lines.length - $scope.pularLnhs); k++) {
            tableVolume.rows[number+k+1].cells[0].innerHTML = volTotal;
            tableVolume.rows[number+k+1].cells[1].innerHTML = lines[($scope.pularLnhs+k)].substring(4);  
            tableVolume.rows[number+k+1].cells[2].innerHTML = "";
            tableVolume.rows[number+k+1].cells[3].innerHTML = "<button class='button-one' onclick='DeleteSrlNumber()'> <i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button>";
        }
    }
};
```

The rest of the code doesn't matter much, so much so that there are names of variables and functions that I didn't give details. What matters to me is the line

```
tableVolume.rows[number+k+1].cells[3].innerHTML = "<button class='button-one' onclick='DeleteSrlNumber()'> <i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button>";
```

where I add a button to each row in the table automatically. Well, I can add the button but I can't connect that button to a function, for example, when clicking the button it will delete the line where it is.

[image]

How would I do that? Link a function to this button that I created using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
// Insert the button
tableVolume.rows[number+k+1].cells[3].innerHTML = 
    "<button class='button-one'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button>";

// Get a reference to the button element (it's the first element of this cell) 
tableVolume.rows[number+k+1].cells[3].firstElementChild
// And assign a click listener that removes this row (but it can do whatever you want)
    .addEventListener("click", function() { 
        tableVolume.rows[number+k+1].remove();
    })
```

I've also made a live demo here https://jsfiddle.net/ecmoqtbf/14/.

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers specified as html attributes will look for javascript identifiers in the global scope. So in your present scenario, if `DeleteSrlNumber()` is declared globally, it should actually be called on click.

If you want to access identifiers that are non-global, then you could do something like this:

```
var button = document.createElement("button")
button.addEventListener("click", function() { 
   DeleteSrlNumber()
})
tableVolume.rows[number+k+1].cells[3].appendChild(button)
```

Note in this case that the identifiers, even though non-global, should still be in scope.